# Automatically generate BibTeX item from arxiv

Tags: arxiv, bibliography

I'm looking for a tool which generates a BibTeX item for a given arxiv id. I only found http://www.crcg.de/arXivToBibTeX/ using Google but this tool always tells me that the arxiv ids I enter don't exist which is of course not true.

Edit: For example http://www.crcg.de/arXivToBibTeX/?q=1503.06747&format=bibtex gives the error message "No paper with the ID “1503.06747” could be found on the arXiv." even though it exists: http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06747

Edit (by author of the discussed arXiv2BibTeX tool): Sorry for the inconvenience! The feedback website didn’t send us the e-mails with notes about the problem, so it took a while to discover your feedback. The tool is working again now at https://arxiv2bibtex.org/ with a proper github issue tracker at https://github.com/ssp/arXivToBibTeX/issues .

Comment: Please provide an id for which it fails. Also, please consider leaving a comment (bottom of the page) there, with a “bug report”.

Comment: Should this be migrated to TeX.SE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs on TeX.SE

Comment: You might want to try [martin-thoma.de/arxiv.php](http://www.martin-thoma.de/arxiv.php)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you omit the initial zero after the dot in the identifier, it [works](http://www.crcg.de/arXivToBibTeX/?q=1503.6747&format=bibtex).

I guess that the tool does some formatting mojo that hasn't been updated when arXiv [switched to 5-digit identifiers](http://arxiv.org/help/arxiv_identifier) last January.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Mac, you may find the following [arXiv to BibDesk](http://earthlingsoft.net/ssp/arXivToBibDesk/) applescript based solution useful.

In summary, suppose you are at an arXiv page for a paper. Then, an execution of the above script does the following:

1. Downloads the PDF from arXiv into a folder managed by BibDesk (to a running instance)
2. Adds a bibliographic entry to BibDesk

Moreover, since this is BibDesk you can generate a "cite key" of your choice by pressing CMD-K, and also rename the arXiv PDF as per paper title / author names if you want.